# Flutter : This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, mobile

I have a problem with the two lines
after adding async and await
a new two errors appear in the await lines

"This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used."

this is the code with the problem

```
  void onTextFieldSubmitted(String input) async {
    
    await fetchSearch(input);
    await fetchLocation();
    
  }
```

you can see the source code here
https://github.com/Akhele/Flutter-Weather-App/blob/master/lib/main.dart

Comment: change return type of your function to ```Future<void>```.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change your methods to 'Future':

```
Future<void> fetchSearch(String input) async {
```

and

```
Future<void>  fetchLocation() async {
```